# How to NOT pass arguments to parameters with default values in Data Binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-xml, android-databinding

Is it possible to call Kotlin function with default parametrs from XML without passing arguments

This is my ViewModel:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel(){

    fun doSomething(myVar: String = "defValue"){

    }
}
```

XML:

```
....
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.MyViewModel" />
</data>
....
android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewModel.doSomething()}"  --> ERROR
android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewModel.doSomething(`SomeString`)}"  --> WORKING
....
```

When I call the `doSomething` method *without argument* from XML with Data Binding I am getting error.

```
[databinding] {"msg":"cannot find method doSomething() in class com.example.MyViewModel","file":"app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_list.xml","pos":[{"line0":56,"col0":41,"line1":56,"col1":65}]}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Annotate your Kotlin method with `@JvmOverloads`. Java does not have a concept of default parameters. This annotation has the Kotlin compiler generate a no-argument method, so you can call it from Java and from your databinding XML in turn.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-overloads/

Comment: Great answer, totally forgot about this `@JvmOverloads` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Great question @DeveScie

The reason it failed is because the `doSomething()` without any parameter function does not exists in byte code level. To understand, you need to see how your kotlin code is converted into Java byte code.

Here is your class's Java representation *(some unrelated code is omitted)*

```java
public final class MyViewModel {
   public final void doSomething(@NotNull String myVar) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(myVar, "myVar");
   }

   // $FF: synthetic method
   public static void doSomething$default(MyViewModel var0, String var1, int var2, Object var3) {
      if ((var2 & 1) != 0) {
         var1 = "defValue";
      }

      var0.doSomething(var1);
   }
}
```

And here is a Kotlin test class that uses this function

```kotlin
class TestClass {
    fun testFunction() {
        val vm = MyViewModel()
        vm.doSomething()
        vm.doSomething("Value")
    }
}
```

Which results in Java code below

```
public final class TestClass {
   public final void testFunction() {
      MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
      MyViewModel.doSomething$default(vm, (String)null, 1, (Object)null);
      vm.doSomething("Value");
   }
}
```

As you can see, the default value you have in kotlin is actually called by:

```
MyViewModel.doSomething$default(vm, (String)null, 1, (Object)null);
```

So, you should have a separate method for other case. Hope it helps.

---

**UPDATE:** Based on @Uli's answer below, another solution is to add `@JvmOverloads` to your kotlin function.

```kotlin
class MyViewModel {
    @JvmOverloads
    fun doSomething(myVar: String = "defValue") {
    }
}
```

Now becomes following in Java

```java
public final class MyViewModel {
    @JvmOverloads
    public final void doSomething() {
        doSomething$default(this, (String) null, 1, (Object) null);
    }

    @JvmOverloads
    public final void doSomething(@NotNull String myVar) {
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(myVar, "myVar");
    }

    // $FF: synthetic method
    public static void doSomething$default(MyViewModel var0, String var1, int var2, Object var3) {
        if ((var2 & 1) != 0) {
            var1 = "defValue";
        }

        var0.doSomething(var1);
    }
}
```

Thanks Uli for reminding me about this option.

Comment: @DeveScie, you can actually use solution mentioned by **Uli** below. I've updated answer to mention that.